# whyDidYouRender npm package crashes the app when one of the children component is marked true for whyDidYouRender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand the react re-rendering process. I am currently using whyDidYouRender npm package along with the fairly straightforward Counter increment/decrement app.

The app works fine in following conditions without crashing.

1. When used without enabling the whyDidYouRender npm package.
2. When whyDidYouRender is enabled on Parent component, the relevant console.log messages are displayed on the console.

When whyDidYouRender is enabled on ChangeCount {children} component, the app crashes during increment/decrement counter.

I will appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to counter the issue.

Link to whyDidYouRender NPM package:- https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render#readme

wdyr.js

```
import React from "react";
const whyDidYouRender = require("@welldone-software/why-did-you-render");
whyDidYouRender(React, {
      onlyLogs: true,
      titleColor: "green",
      diffNameColor: "aqua",
});
```

index.js

```
import "./wdyr";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ErrorBoundary from "./components/hooksTesting/ErrorBoundary";

const DisplayTitle = () => {
  console.count(`render DisplayTitle`);
  return (
    <div style={styles.mainWrapper3}>
      <h1 style={styles.display3}>HOOKS TESTING APP</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const DisplayCount = ({ count }) => {
  console.count(`render DisplayCount`);
  return (
    <div style={styles.mainWrapper2}>
      <h1 style={styles.display2}>THE CURRENT VALUE IS {count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const ChangeCount = ({ showCurrentValue }) => {
  console.count(`render ChangeCount`);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const incr = () => setValue(value + 1);
  const decr = () => value > 0 && setValue(value - 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const myfunc = () => {
      value >= 0 && showCurrentValue(value);
    };
    myfunc();
  }, [value, showCurrentValue]);
  return (
    <div style={styles.buttonCompWrapper}>
      <button style={styles.mybtn} onClick={incr}>
        +1
      </button>
      <button style={styles.mybtn} onClick={decr}>
        -1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  console.count(`render Parent`);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const showCurrentValue = (value) => setCount(value);
  return (
    <div style={styles.mainWrapper1}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <DisplayTitle />
        <DisplayCount count={count}></DisplayCount>
        <ChangeCount showCurrentValue={showCurrentValue}></ChangeCount>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  buttonCompWrapper: {
    width: "50vw",
    height: "20vh",
    background: "grey",
  },
  mybtn: {
    margin: "1vh 2vw",
    padding: "1vh 1vw",
    background: "pink",
  },
  mainWrapper1: {
    width: "90vw",
    height: "90vh",
    background: "black",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    aliginItems: "center",
  },

  display1: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: "2vw",
  },
  mainWrapper2: {
    width: "50vw",
    height: "20vh",
    background: "pink",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    aliginItems: "center",
  },

  display2: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: "2vw",
  },
  mainWrapper3: {
    width: "50vw",
    height: "20vh",
    background: "blue",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    aliginItems: "center",
  },

  display3: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: "2vw",
  },
};

ChangeCount.whyDidYouRender=true;



ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Parent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Error message:-

[image: App Error Message]

Comment: Can you recreate in a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj

Comment: Done.   https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-6xxzw?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

You are using not stable version of the package (`5.0.0-alpha.2`) by downgrading it to stable version there is no error.

You should tackle this problem in package's Github as it pre-released.

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-o8r55?file=/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much. After downgrading to 4.3.1 it works like a charm.